# Autolaunched flow stopped sending fault emails when triggered via Process Builder

Tags: visual-workflow

I have a Process in Process Builder that triggers an autolaunched Flow and passes it a Record id.

Normally, when the Flow triggered by the Process fails, I would receive two emails:

1. One from the process builder, with a generic "An error occurred when executing a flow interview."
2. Another from the flow in question, with a detailed execution path and a precise reason for failure

However, I suddenly stopped receiving the second email - I only get a generic info from process builder, which makes debugging really difficult.

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: did you check Junk email folder?

Comment: Have you looked at [Control Who Receives Flow and Process Error Emails](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/summer18/release-notes/rn_forcecom_flow_email_apex.htm)

Comment: @mPeixoto Yes, checked spam.

Comment: @codeyinthecloud Checked that too, although no changes were made to the configuration.

Comment: are you the last person that updated the flow?

Comment: @mPeixoto Yes, I am the last person that updated the flow.

Comment: If you're last modified and you're part of exception emails and checked your spam and it's still the behaviour you can try raising a case. In the meanwhile you can however [debug](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=vpm_debug.htm&type=5) without the actual email. Make sure you do this in a sandbox instead of prod!

Comment: @codeyinthecloud Thanks, I did raise a ticket as it’s really unusual. I am aware of the Debugging tool, it just takes much longer to debug specific cases with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After four weeks of back and forth with Salesforce support, I can confirm the issue is in fact a known Salesforce bug to be resolved with Winter '19 Critical Update called: **"Check for Null Record Variables or Null Values of Lookup Relationship Fields in Process and Flow Formulas".**

The critical update was already available in our Sandbox instance. After activating it, the issue is gone and fault emails work as expected.

Here is the official description of the problem:
https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/spring19/release-notes/rn_forcecom_flow_cruc_formula.htm

The only workaround suggested by SFDC support was to create fault lines at every step of the autolaunched flow and send emails manually.